# How can I add an addional option to open URLs from GnomeTerminal using Chrome's "incognito" mode?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, google-chrome, gnome-terminal

The menu is offering "Open Link" and "Copy Link", but for some cases (like Spam or Phishing E-Mails) I'd like to have a context-menu entry "Open Link in Incognito". How can this be done?

Comment: are you asking about the command to open a link in incognito mode in chromium ?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to add this to a context-sensitive menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this cannot be easily done.

The entire GNOME ecosystem (and probably other popular desktops too) knows the concept of *one* associated application per protocol or MIME type. Applications such as `GNOME Terminal` just call the `gtk_show_uri()` method on the URL, which opens it with the associated application.

In `Settings` (that is, `gnome-control-center`) -> `Details` -> `Default Applications` you can set the *one* application that handles Web (http, https) links. Under the hood, this modifies your `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file. Inside this file, under its `Default Applications` section you'll see a line like `text/html=chromium-browser.desktop`, referring to the `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` file.

Whereas the latter file can (and does) define various `Desktop Action`s (one for private mode), there's no existing convenient infrastructure I'm aware of to propagate the available actions back to the application (such as `GNOME Terminal`) to let it pick one, and then open the URL using that action.

It would be a nice feature, though, if it was consistently supported throughout the entire GNOME desktop. I think it first requires infrastructure work in core components such as GTK+ and perhpas even the `.desktop` file specification, and then apps like `GNOME Terminal` could adapt it. Unfortunately it's not really feasible for `GNOME Terminal` to work around the existing infrastructure and implement it itself. I'd *love* if you filed this feature request for GNOME (although I cannot guarantee that its developers would love it too), and I'd be happy to adjust `GNOME Terminal` whenever it's available.

One thing you can do is, if you'd like to open *all* the URLs in incognito mode, is to create a corresponding new desktop file (where Chrome is launched in incognito mode by default), and make it your default handler for web addresses.

Another approach you could take is to modify gnome-terminal's source. Duplicate whatever you find around the keywords `open-match`, `open_match`, `terminal_util_open_url` and `open_url` to have an incognito mode counterpart. At the end of `open_url_incognito` (or whatever you name it) you'd replace `gtk_show_uri()` by manually launching whatever external process you wish to launch, taking care of properly quoting/escaping the URL if necessary.

Yet another workaround, which you've presumably been doing already, is to select `Copy Link` from `GNOME Terminal`'s menu, and then paste it into an incognito browser's URL bar. I understand you're looking for a more convenient method, and I'm sorry to say that it doesn't exist.